# Related rate word problem.

Tags: calculus

Here is the problem:

> A kite 100 ft above the ground moves horizontally at a speed of `8 ft/s`. At what rate is the angle between the string and the horizontal decreasing when 200 ft of string has been let out?

So I drew a triangle with a hypotenuse of 200 and a missing side of x and a third side of 100. So here is my equation:

$$100cot(\theta) = x$$

$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = 100 (-csc^2{\theta}) \frac{d\theta}{dx}$$

I'm stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guide:

$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = 100 (-csc^2{\theta}) \frac{d\theta}{d\color{red}t}$$

Note that $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is given to us. Also, we should be able to compute $\theta$ since we know $200$ ft of strings has been left out (hypothenus) and the height is $100$. Then we can solve for $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$

Comment: Can I see it? I'm stil la bit lost

Comment: which part are you stuck? do you know what is $\frac{dx}{dt}$? Do you know what is $\theta$?

Comment: I see so we have the \frac{dx}{dt}, we can also computer theta since we have two sides, and therefore the only thing left is \frac{d\theta}{dt} right?

Comment: yup, and $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$ is what we want to obtain in the end.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can we solve for the third side since it's a right triangle? Is the third side 173.20?

Comment: Is the answer $8 = -200 \frac{d\theta}{dt}$? or $ - 0.04 = \frac{d\theta}{dt}$? Should the 8 be negative or positive? why?